# Cannot change input-language (using Alt+Shift) over NX session

Tags: 12.04, input-language, nx

I can't seem to change the language over an NX session.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and locally I just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to alter language.
When I connect to a remote server using NX , I can not use this key combination to alter the language I type at the far end.

I am sure the nxserver is working - used to use it  for a long time. I changed my local OS though (was running Mint 12, and now I'm running ubuntu 12.04). So I had to reinstall Nomachine's NX, and now it is not working.

Any clues?

- I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Caps</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> but that doesn't work.

Comment: Try with Shift + CapsLock.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu nope, that doesn't work.

Comment: Try `Alt+SpaceBar`.

Comment: @Mitch, that does not work either. Does it work for you? Is this even the key combination you use to change languages locally? This is not a key combination issue. when I press `Alt+Shift` I still get to language indication to switch locally. It is just that on the far end, this switching does not occur. I still type in english remotely...!

Answer (score 0):

follow me...
go to system settings then click on keyboard layout
click on '+' and select your language
the click on options
go to "keys to change layout"
then mark 'Alt+Shift'

Answer (score 0):

You say the language indication changes locally, so the actual Alt+Shift shortcut doesn't even get there. You could change one side's shortcut so that they don't conflict anymore (I don't think anything, other than virtual machines and Microsoft remote desktop products -- which I can't see fit -- could completely hook up the keyboard)

If you could hook the keyboard input of the program and made it get the input of the X server itself, then yes, that's a more complicated way of alleviating the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use probably already installed utility from package `x11-xkb-utils` and try it either on host or connected guest.

```
setxkbmap fr # French keyboard
```